# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[\sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2^r}\right]$ where [] is integer part function.

Tags: limits, functions

I have tried this using summation of infinite GP and getting the answer as 1 but in my book answer is 0. Can anybody tell me how??

Comment: Evaluate the summation manually, separately, for each $n \in \{2,3,4\}$, and you will see a pattern.  You can use this pattern to form a hypothesis, and then prove this hypothesis.  A **consequence** of the hypothesis will be that the summation is always $< 1$, regardless of the value of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $[x]=n\in\mathbb{Z}$ iff $n\leq x<n+1$.
Since $0<s_n:=\sum^n_{k=1}2^{-k}<1$ for all $n$,  $[s_n]=0$ for all $n$ and so,
$\lim_n[s_n]=0$.

Notice that $x\mapsto[x]$ is not continuous at any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, that is why $\lim_n[s_n]<[\lim_ns_n]=[1]=1$